# OFDM symbol, data amount

Tags: wireless

I'm new to OFDM, so I have a basic question.

I have a 8 channel OFDM using 8PSK. To me a single symbol using 8PSK means 8 bits, hence one byte of data. Since I have 8 channels, that would mean 64 bytes. This would equate to a single OFDM symbol of 64 bytes?

Going on further a payload of 16 OFDM symbols would mean 16*64 bytes of data.

I'm not too sure of the relationship between bits, symbols and OFDM symbols even though it appears to be simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8PSK means an eight symbol alphabet that have different phases. The Number of bits you can represent with an alphabet of size 8 is log2(8) = 3 bits.

Depending on the number of carriers/channels the total bits is

Carrier number * 3

I think I this would represent the number of bits in a single OFDM symbol.